# Working with compareTo() method of Comparable interface

Tags: java, comparable

I have one Employee class and the requirement is to sort the objects using comparable interface. The output with this code is:

```
The difference of this id and other id is..** 6  other id**1
The difference of this id and other id is..** 3  other id**6
The difference of this id and other id is..** 3  other id**6
The difference of this id and other id is..** 3  other id**1
The difference of this id and other id is..** 11  other id**3
The difference of this id and other id is..** 11  other id**6
[Employee [name=lalit, id=1], Employee [name=zanjan, id=3], Employee [name=rmit, id=6], Employee [name=harjot, id=11]]
```

```
public class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    private String name;
    private Integer id;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + "]";
    }

    public Employee(Integer id, String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Integer id() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setID(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Employee o) {
        System.out.println("The difference of this id and other id is..** " + id + "  other id**" + o.id);
        System.out.println(this.id);
        System.out.println(o.id);
        return this.id - o.id;
    }
}

import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
public class ComparableDemo
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Employee e1 = new Employee(1, "lalit");
        Employee e2 = new Employee(6, "rmit");
        Employee e3 = new Employee(3, "zanjan");
        Employee e4 = new Employee(11, "harjot");
        List<Employee> empList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        empList.add(e1);
        empList.add(e2);
        empList.add(e3);
        empList.add(e4);
        Collections.sort(empList);
        System.out.println(empList);
    }
}
```

My questions are:

1. How the first comparison would be between 6 & 1?
2. How number 6 is assigned to `this.id`?
3. What is the need of comparing 3 & 6 twice, both in the second and third line of output?
4. How does the `compareTo` method actually work? How does this subtraction lead to sorting using Comparable?
5. What are the values for `this.id` and how are these values assigned to `this.id`?

Comment: and what is your input ??

Comment: That's a lot of question... **1)** this is the order of your list ... **2)** because the constructor is setting the `id` parameter to the `id` member variable. **4)** your are defining the logic to order elements. **5)** already asked in 2)... for **3)** this is the algorithm used, you can check yourself the logic used.

Answer (score 2):

> 1. How the first comparison would be between 6 & 1?

The elements in the list which are checked first depends on the sorting algorithm used by [`Collection.sort(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List)). It is an implementation detail of the internal sort algorithm.

> 2. How number 6 is assigned to `this.id`?

You set it inside your constructor.

> 3. What is the need of comparing 3 & 6 twice, both in the second and third line of output?

It's not like that the algorithm wants to compare these objects twice, but that at some point in the algorithm it compared them and later due to the algorithm it compares them again at a different stage of the algorithm. Again, that is an implementation detail of the internal sort algorithm.

> 4. How does the `compareTo` method actually work? How does this subtraction lead to sorting using Comparable?

When the sorting algorithm from `Collection.sort(...)` is running, at some point during the algorithm it needs to compare two objects and calculate which of these two objects comes before the other one in order (not necessary next to each other, just "somewhere before"). The return value of the `compareTo()` method specifies how the "this" object is positioned relative to the given argument object. Based on these objects the `compareTo()` object must return a value either "less than zero", "equal zero" or "greater than zero". See [the documentation of the `Comparable` interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html)  which value should be returned when.

> 5. What are the values for `this.id` and how are these values assigned to `this.id`?

As answered for the second question, the field is set in your constructor.